# Interrupt a global search and replace with confirmation

Tags: search-replace

Far too often, I've started a global search replace with confirmation, and discovered part way thru that I should have done a different search.    Here's a silly example

```
he
he1
he
the2
he
them
```

Suppose my goal was to change all occurences of the word `he` with `she` and I unfortunately wrote

```
:g/he/s//she/gc
```

and wanted to interrupt the operation after the second change.    Obviously I could enter `n` or `CTRL C` till I got to the end but when there are lots of candidates this gets pretty tedious.    What I'd like to be able to do is simply cancel the search in midstream, but as far as I can tell this is not possible.    Or is it?

Comment: `ctrl-c` interrupts the whole `g/` expression

Comment: for me, ctrl-c interrupts each individual replacement, but i have to hit ctrl c for as many times as there are instances of the search.    Is that normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your command as `:%substitute/{pat}/{repl}/gc` which is equivalent (in this particular case), and use `<esc>` or `q` to stop substituting.

The difference is `:global/{pat}/substitute//{repl}/gc` runs a separate and independent susbtitute command for each line matching `{pat}`, while `:%substitute…` runs a single command over the whole file.

Comment: Perfect and thanks for the explanation